# How to convert a .ods file to .csv?

Tags: python, file, csv, xlrd, ods

I've used xlrd for .xlsx files, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent for .ods files.
How can I convert some_file.ods to some_file.csv using python?

Comment: Googling for `python ods` returns [pyexcel-ods](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel-ods/) and `pyexcel-ods3`. Have you tried it?

Comment: It doesn't offer file conversion

Comment: You don't *need* file conversion when you can already read the data. If you want to write that data out as a CSV, you can just write to a text file (csv is just a text file after all) or use [pyexcel](http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/tutorial_data_conversion.html#how-to-open-an-xls-file-and-save-it-as-csv) to read from one format and write to another

Comment: [pandas_ods_reader](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ods-reader/)

Answer (score 2):

`pip install odspy`

pandas uses it to read ods files.

To convert to cvs w/pandas:

python

```html
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('my_excel.ods')
df.to_csv('my_excel.csv')
```

Comment: `odfpy` may also be needed in addition to `odspy`